# PHP: How Read From custom JSON

Tags: php, json

I have an URL that fetches me JSON data like this:-

```
[
    {
        MatchId: "17792",
        MatchDate: "3/20/2017 3:00:00 AM",
        MatchStatus: "",
        RoundDetails: "الجولة ( 13 )",
        ChampionID: "151",
        ChampionName: "تصفيات كأس العالم - امريكا الجنوبية",
        ChampionLogo: "730109bd-ba13-4906-8349-4cb12609dd1f.png",
        Team1ID: "7",
        Team1Name: "اوروقواي",
        Team1Logo: "457e035b-af0a-4858-bec5-730e2b50735c.png",
        Team1Result: "",
        Team2ID: "3",
        Team2Name: "البرازيل",
        Team2Logo: "07df2e50-3ce2-4091-b4a9-8e6e1aa2272d.png",
        Team2Result: ""
    },
    {
        MatchId: "17793",
        MatchDate: "3/20/2017 3:00:00 AM",
        MatchStatus: "",
        RoundDetails: "الجولة ( 13 )",
        ChampionID: "151",
        ChampionName: "تصفيات كأس العالم - امريكا الجنوبية",
        ChampionLogo: "730109bd-ba13-4906-8349-4cb12609dd1f.png",
        Team1ID: "8",
        Team1Name: "كولومبيا",
        Team1Logo: "2d68377c-61ec-4c38-a334-3fc1a51e2bbd.png",
        Team1Result: "",
        Team2ID: "13",
        Team2Name: "بوليفيا",
        Team2Logo: "b07b9eb3-c49c-46ed-92a0-bb55e7f869fa.png",
        Team2Result: ""
    }
]
```

How can I read all array using `foreach` and store all values to table in database.

I would appreciate an example for this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an "ask it and we do it for you" site. What have you tried?

Comment: $arr_result = json_decode($json_data,true); Now you get an array of json data . Then using foreach you can access element

Comment: decode your json using [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) then loop over it and insert your data into mysql using pdo or mysqli extension

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$data = json_decode($your_json_string, TRUE);

foreach ($data as $key => $singleObj) {
     // store require data in your db
}
```